# what is the best way to transition from login screen to home screen, UI layout and code

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

A newbie programmer here trying make my own app and I am having a difficult time finding the answer on the best way to switch from your login screen to the apps main view controller. I am using Parse login and sign up view controllers. Sorry for the newbie question, but until i can get that figured out I'm at a roadblock :( thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the section of your code where you have achieved a successful login add this.

```
      self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yoursegueIdentifer", sender: self)
```

See if this helps clear up the process.

```
 @IBAction func acceptPassword(sender: UIButton) {
    let passCodeValue = defaults.stringForKey("passCode")
    // check if what was typed = stored pass code
    if passCodeValue == passCodeText.text {
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("tableVC", sender: self)
       }else {
        let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "ALERT!!", message: "Pass code incorrect", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
        passCodeText.text = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey MwcsMac! I've seen people use this and I have tried to use it but am having issues, can you help me understand what view controller i should start at as my "initial view controller"? i have a login screen which segues to a sign up screen if needed and then a homesceen. Just confused on what order i should start the app. with the home screen and put segue if not logged in or with the login....sorry if I'm confusing you..ive confused myself over this ha

Comment: First do you use a navigation controller if so then it should be set as the initial view controller.  Are forcing the user to login every time?

Answer (score 0):

Use a presented view controller on top of the main view controller to show the login screen. That way, you just dismiss the login screen and now you are back at the main view controller.

Comment: Using segue and unwinding is much better option.

Comment: thanks for the reply matt!! should i put the presentviewcontroller method under the home screen class? should it be the first code under my home screen view controller class?

Comment: @avi I haven't used an unwinding segue before, any tips or good resources on how to use it? thanks!